# Descriptografar email IMAP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, criptografia, base64

Estou recebendo emails na minha aplicação através de IMAP, e tudo está aparecendo da maneira certa, exceto o texto que está criptografado, como faço para descriptografar ou configurar para ele não ser criptografado??

Estou usando a biblioteca [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) para receber e a biblioteca [Mailparser](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/) para fazer o parse dos emails, porém é a primeira vez que estou trabalhando com essa questão de emails e não possuo experiência no assunto, quem puder me ajudar, agradeço...

Parte de um dos headers, todos seguem o mesmo padrão:

```
{ attachments:
   [ { type: 'attachment',
       content: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 0a 07 07 09 07 06 0a 09 08 09 0b 0b 0a 0c 0f 19 10 0f 0e 0e 0f 1e 16 17 12 ... >,
       contentType: 'image/jpeg',
       release: null,
       filename: 'image001.jpg',
```

Está em base64:

```
 D7VuDOYyQMcCqllqbCwt3nEm+5yyfKcA4zjJPI6n8Kn09WgchyDHKuD/smpzplqiKiW6BVOVHp9PSuVzgk1NXPrcvhJUkox5Wt0/lqZ51rbFG4B4MZkYrwVb0Gc9qnuLq31e2e1jR2cjfGCMZIAJGfowqymn24GPJTHyjGPTp+WaSaOOyw9pB
```

Mas pelo o que eu vi acho que é a imagem da assinatura do email que eu recebi, pois essa assinatura contém uma imagem. Estou meio perdido porque nunca trabalhei com isso antes...

Comment: É muita coisa para conseguir colocar aqui, vai dar centenas de linhas. Tem como eu postar em outro lugar e você olhar lá??

Comment: Coloca só o código proximo, o que recebe esse objeto por exemplo.

Comment: A qual objeto você se refere??

Comment: Esse `{ attachments:...` é um objeto JavaScript. Coloca a função que recebe isso.

Comment: Como posso te enviar um arquivo TXT com o código todo? É muita coisa que veio na saída do console.

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/ - mas não coloques nada pessoal/privado. Depois podes colocar o link aqui na pergunta

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/ZPzVn6qHF5phBi4YGpDwGU#  -> Saída do console
https://paste.ofcode.org/34UihdFmjM8akHvtnSd8b8m -> Código que pega o email e que também faz o parse

Tomei o devido cuidado e retirei todos os dados pessoais que achei

Comment: Esse `console.log` vem de que linha no código?

Comment: Na parte `simpleParser(source)
        .then(mail=>{
         console.log(mail)
        })` 

É onde sai aquilo que coloquei no link de saída do console, na linha 31